# How can I get an element with getElementById found in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to do something like this:

```
<div id="parent">
  <iframe id="myFrame" title="HEY!" srcdoc="<div id='inner'>Hello World!</div>"></iframe>
</div>
var parent = document.getElementById("parent").innerHTML;
var title = parent.getElementById("myFrame").title;
```

But this throws an error like innerHTML doesn't have getElementById attribute.
How can I get the title of the iframe element in the innerHTML.
Note: It must be inside the innerHTML element.

Comment: Just use `var parent = document.getElementById("parent")` forget the `.innerHTML` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");

var title = parent.querySelector("#myFrame").title;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `.innerHTML` returns a string, not a DOM element. So as many suggested, you should remove this.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var title = parent.getElementById("myFrame").title;
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <iframe id="myFrame" title="HEY!" srcdoc="<div id='inner'>Hello World!</div>"></iframe>
</div>
```

BUT THIS NOT ONLY OUTPUTS AN ERROR, BUT IT ALSO DOESN'T WORK !

It would for `getElementByClassName()` and `getElementByTagName()`, but that's not the point...

You are running the `getElementById()` method on an element, and this doesn't work : why would you run this method scoped ? what's the point as IDs have to be unique (but not classes or tags) ?

So here, this is enough :

```js
var title = document.getElementById("myFrame").title;
console.log(title);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <iframe id="myFrame" title="HEY!" srcdoc="<div id='inner'>Hello World!</div>"></iframe>
</div>
```

EDIT :
Just to make things clear :

You can only call `getElementByID()` on `document` as discussed [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-typeerror-getelementbyid-is-not-a-function#calling-the-getelementbyid-on-an-element-that-is-not-the-document)